# Procedure returning no value in data table using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I want to use following stored procedure which contains pivot query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE YarnStockList
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        YarnId,
        Receive,
        Issued,
        Claim,
        Total = Receive - Issued - Claim
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             YarnId, Status, Bags
         FROM 
             Yarn_IssueReceive) AS PivotData
    PIVOT
        (SUM(bags) FOR Status IN (Receive, Issued, Damage, Claim)
    END) AS Pivoting
```

[Output of procedure in sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewmoa.png)
My class is

```
public class Yarn_IssueRecieve
{
     public int Bags { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public int YarnId { get; set; }
}
```

Using following code returns an empty result:

```
using (var db = new ATMSEntityModel())
{
    var que = db.Database.SqlQuery<Yarn_IssueRecieve>("EXEC YarnStockList").ToList();

    gridControl1.DataSource = que.ToList();
}
```

How can I execute this in Entity Framework to pass in data table with same columns in my procedure?

Comment: Can you show us a sample output of your stored procedure in tabular format along with headers? You can edit your question to include it.

Comment: @Priyank edited

Answer (score 4):

Add property to class Yarn_IssueRecieve as per the select list of SP 
or Create a new view model just like bellow

```
public class Yarn_IssueRecieveViewModel
{
        public int YarnId { get; set; }
        // decimal/float/int as it is returned by the SP. 
        public decimal Receive { get; set; }
        public decimal Issued { get; set; }
        public decimal Claim { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

Then change the return type Yarn_IssueRecieve to Yarn_IssueRecieveViewModel

```
var que = db.Database.SqlQuery<Yarn_IssueRecieveViewModel>("EXEC YarnStockList").ToList();
```

Comment: @AyeshaSheikh, you can tick mark this as an answer so that others will be able to find it